# glPolygonMode producing unexpected lines

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

this is an ongoing issue I am having when calling

glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

At first I have thought it had something to do with polygon offsets or triangle strips. 
Below the large gif is an example of what it looked like in immediate mode with triangle strips.
The top picture shows what it looks like with VBO triangles (it's a hard to see in the gif but it does the same thing). There are random lines that pop in
and out and change length while moving. After calling glPolygonMode lines I always
call fill afterwards. Below the images is my code for drawing the line VBOs.

[image]

[image]

```
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);  
        glLineWidth(1.0f);
        glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.08f);
        glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE);
        glPolygonOffset (-5.8f, -1.0f);
        glEnable (GL_BLEND); 
        glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vHandle);
        glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 3 << 2, 0L); 

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, count /* elements */);
        glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);   
        glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE);
```

Comment: This is in java. I am using a library called lwjgl. [Here is a link to the ARBBufferObject doc.](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/ARBBufferObject.html) The method parameters looks like this glBufferDataARB(int target, java.nio.FloatBuffer data, int usage).

Comment: But also I should note that the same exact issue happened when dealing with immediate mode. Which makes me think that wouldn't be an issue??